# Android studio unable to paste files to assets folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I want to use some fonts but when I try to paste the ttf files into a fonts folder that I have in the assets folder, it just does not do anything. And yes, I am sure that I copied the files.

Comment: Right click on the folder and click on *Show in Explorer* and check if the files are there.

Comment: @forpas It didn’t do anything when I clicked on that.

Comment: You clicked on *Show in Explorer* and nothing happened?

Comment: @forpas exactly

Comment: This is not normal. Do the same to the drawable folder.

Comment: @forpas didn’t do anything.

Comment: As I said this is not normal behavior for Android Studio. Anyway, open the windows File Explorer and go to your app's folder. The assets folder is in `src/main/`.

Comment: I’m there now. Do I paste the files in there?

Comment: If you found the folder, yes paste them.

Comment: @forpas It worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Ok  then, fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevigate to the assets folder in file explorer. It will be at you_app_folder/app/src/main/assets/fonts

Paste the files there.

Now go back to android studio and you should see the files there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "Project" or "Project Files" view in Android Studio to see and copy to the "app/src/main/assets" (or whatever) directory itself.

"app/assets" is an alias in "Android" view of project and I'm thinking that is the problem for paste.